# Is it possible to to use an IAsyncActionFilter within a signalr hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

With a MVC aspnetcore app I can create an IAsyncActionFilter to measure execution time (implemented as an attribute). I'd like to do the same with a Signalr hub controller, but doesn't seem to work.

```cs
    public class TimeFilter : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            await next();
            sw.Stop();
            string logStr = ($"##### {context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName} - EXC: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(logStr);
        }
    }
```

This works (via MVC):

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [TimeFilter]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

This fails (via Signalr, TimeFilter never called):

```cs
    public class SRHub : Hub
    {
        [TimeFilter]
        public async Task Calc(int x, int y)
        {
            await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("CalcResp", x+y);
        }
    }
```

I'm guessing that SignalR isn't using the same pipelining as MVC, but am I missing something, or is this just no possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guessed right , SignalR does not use the same pipelining as MVC. A quick test can be done.

```
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<ChartHub>("/chart");
        });
```

and comment out

```
        //app.UseMvc();
```

You will find the signalR still works.
Middlewares do not seem to work either for this.